# Arithmetaic Operator Generator

Tags: java, android, arrays, math, random

I'm trying to create an android application which will be a simple maths game. It has Multiple Difficulty Levels including easy, medium, hard, Very Hard. Easy level involves the arithmetic question questions between 2 integers(6+6), Medium between 3(2+2-1), Hard between 4(2+2-1/3) and Very Hard between 5(2+3*5-3+2). I have to generate random Integers and random Arithmetic operations. I am able to display the questions and operations for each difficulty level but I can not find the correct Answer. Whatever answer I enter, the programme shows it incorrect. For Example if I answer 3+3-1 as 5 or any other it will always be shown wrong. For 2 Integers I used switch statements, and it worked fine, but the questions involving multiple Arithmetic operations always are wrong any Idea as how to do it. I am Putting the code below

```
    private final int ADD_OPERATOR = 0, SUBTRACT_OPERATOR = 1, MULTIPLY_OPERATOR = 2, DIVIDE_OPERATOR = 3;
    private String[] operators = {"+", "-", "x", "/"};
    operator = random.nextInt(operators.length);

    switch(operator)
    {
    case ADD_OPERATOR:
    answer = operand1+operand2;
    break;
    case SUBTRACT_OPERATOR:
    answer = operand1-operand2;
    break;
    case MULTIPLY_OPERATOR:
    answer = operand1*operand2;
    break;
    case DIVIDE_OPERATOR:
    answer = operand1/operand2;
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
    question.setText(operand1+" "+operators[operator]+" "+operand2);
    //Operand 1 and Operand 2 are 2 Random Integers

     public void onClick(View view)
   {
    //button clicked
    if(view.getId()==R.id.enter){
        //enter button
        String answerContent = answerTxt.getText().toString();
        if(!answerContent.endsWith("?"))
        {
            //we have an answer}
            int enteredAnswer =   Integer.parseInt(answerContent.substring(2));
            int exScore = getScore();

        if(enteredAnswer==answer){
            //correct
            scoreTxt.setText("Score: "+(exScore+1));
            response.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick);
            response.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            //incorrect
            scoreTxt.setText("Score: 0");
            response.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross);
            response.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        chooseQuestion();
    }}
    else if(view.getId()==R.id.clear){
        //clear button
        answerTxt.setText("= ?");
    }
    else {
        //number button
        response.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        int enteredNum = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
        if(answerTxt.getText().toString().endsWith("?"))
            answerTxt.setText("= "+enteredNum);
        else
            answerTxt.append(""+enteredNum);
    }
}
```

I am storing the user answer as answeredtext.
Any help as how to do it for multiple Arithmetic operations. Thanks

Comment: Please post a code for multiple operations and also how do you compare user answer to correct answer.

Comment: I have added the code for storing the user answer as well. Thanks

Comment: Do you at any point check what you actually have in enteredAnswer? try debugging it (eaiest way by creating some onscreen text displaying enteredAnswer value). Display a value of answer also. This way you will know what actual values you have there

Comment: I have check the answer is stored correctly. the problem is that It doesn't work for multiple arithmetic operations.

Comment: so post your code for multiple arihtmetic because this one always creates simple ones.

Comment: That is what i am asking that what should be the code that i can use for them